# Relationship between the transition monoid of an automaton and its adjacency matrix

Tags: reference-request, automata-theory

Let $A=(Q,\Sigma, \Delta, q_0, F)$ be an NFA over an alphabet $\Sigma$, $M(A)$ be its *transition monoid*.

For all $a\in\Sigma$, let $S_a\in\mathbb{B}^{|Q|\times|Q|}$ be the *adjacency matrix* of $A$ relative to $a$, *i.e.*, $S_a(i,j)=1$ iff $(q_i,a,q_j)\in\Delta$.

If I'm not mistaken, $M(A)$ is generated by $S=\{S_a\mid a\in\Sigma\}$ with the usual matrix product and identity (this is also explained in [Pin's book](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejep/PDF/MPRI/MPRI.pdf), page 86, if I didn't misunderstood). This also means we can see each element of $M(A)$ as a matrix.

So are there any useful properties we can get about $M(A)$ from looking at the elements of $M(A)$ as matrices? Maybe some spectral properties?

Comment: Spectral ideas (like eigenvalues) usually assume the matrix is over a field. Have they been generalised to semirings?

Comment: Afaik yes, but I hardly know anything about these things…

Comment: I'd be interested in references for spectral methods on matrices over semirings.

Answer (score 8):

The algebraic view has many useful properties. I think these become more evident when you move from the Boolean setting to richer semirings, e.g., tropical-weighted automata.
At any rate, a celebrated result that uses this view is Simon's Factorization theorem. An excellent survey by Bojanczyk is here:
[https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~bojan/papers/forests-dlt.pdf](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/%7Ebojan/papers/forests-dlt.pdf)

In the tropical semiring you can get pretty far using this view, by examining the generated semigroup (which is not necessarily finite), and defining the so-called *stabilization monoid*, which captures which runs diverge to $\infty$ and which stay bounded.
An application of this can be found in a work on determinization of polynomially ambiguous weighted automata, here:
https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00360205/document

This doesn't really answer your question, but maybe these references will be useful to get the overall gist of this approach.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting references!